# Syntax error, Unexpected '{'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and doing some tutorial and I got stuck with this problem. This is the coe for my model

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Wip_model extends CI_Model
{
function __construct()
{
    // call the model constructor
    parent::__construct();

    // this is the line 14 error
}
}
```

But I am getting this error[image]

Please help.......

this is the function in controller that calls it

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $wipDB = $this->load->database('WIPDB',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // load the model
    $this->load->model('wip_model');
}
```

Comment: I just copied it in the tutorial.....

Comment: can you copy your controller method that call this model? wip.php in line 15

Comment: please try to remove `__construct` function and see if it cause error again (debugging)

Comment: Ok I resolve my problem by removing the loading of my model page and the error message is gone and my webpage is loading again..

Comment: it means, u have only problem in wip_model

Comment: I don't know because in the tutorial it's working but when I applied it in my own code that starts the error. By the way these the link to the tutorial that I have read http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/codeigniter-bootstrap-insert-form-data-into-database.html

Comment: logically your method is true , because you call your parent model 2 times one with `$this->load->model` another with `__construct`

Comment: In your model you are missing <?php make sure your file name of model is Wip_model.php

Comment: Can you add where u use $this->wip_model->function()

Comment: I already posted my solution and kindly read the other comments because you're asking a question that was already been answered by others..